Tailwind configuration with the React does not work [Specified input file ./src/input.css does not exist.]
I followed this instruction to configure react with tailwind css tailwind docs
Node.js v22.1.0
PS D:\vscode\my-project> npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch
Specified input file ./src/input.css does not exist.

I have been trying to configure my first React app with Tailwind and I keep getting this error from this point.

Did you verify that ./src/input.css does exist?

You can try these steps.
1. Instal Tailwind + autoprefix + postcss:
autoprefix and postcss are some additional tools you may find useful.
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

2. Generate Tailwind config files: This will create two files in your project, tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js.
npx tailwindcss init -p

3. Configure Tailwind : paste this in tailwind.config.js.
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

4. Add Tailwind to Your CSS: open your global css file, src/index.css (assuming default react app) and add these directives to the top of the file.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/*the rest of your css*/

Then restart your app and you should be good to go. Hope this helps.
